# On functional equation $f\circ \exp=\exp \circ Df$ on a Riemannian manifold or a Lie Group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, functional-equations

Let $M$ be  a  Riemannian manifold  or  a  Lie  group whose  corresponding exp map (in corresponding context) is denoted by "exp"  which is  a  map $\exp:TM\to M$

We search  for the  set  $\mathcal{H}$  of   all smooth maps $f:M\to M$ which satisfy $$f\circ \exp=\exp \circ Df$$

Is there  a  natural finite  dimensional  manifold  structure on  $\mathcal{H}$?  In the case that $M$ is  a  Lie  group, is  there a Lie  group structure on $\mathcal{H}$? In either case what can be said about the dimension of $\mathcal{H}$?

**Example:** For  Lie  group $M=\mathbb{R}$ we get $\mathcal{H}=\{ax+b\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ the  additive  group of  all affine  linear maps on $\mathbb{R}$, a $2$ dimensional Abelian lie group isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, it's a Lie group -- the defining equation you mention, that the maps commute with exponentiation this tells you your maps are determined by their behaviour on a basis for one tangent space.   So the Lie group is at most $m + m^2$ dimensional.  Presumably this is only realized for $\mathbb R^m$.  I imagine for a compact Riemann manifold this is the isometry group.

Comment: @RyanBudney For a Riemannian manifold every constant map satisfies this equation so the last part of your comment is not true. Let me think about the first part of your comment. Please read my question again in particular the example in the last part of my post.

Comment: @RyanBudney note that a possible group structure on $\mathcal{H}$ is not probably defined via composition but it possibly comes from the group structure of $G$, as it is the case in the example of the post.

Comment: @RyanBudney appart from constant map you can find other maps for example $z\mapsto z^2$ on circle, right?

Comment: My Lie group comment refers to the maps where Df is invertible.  I suppose I imagined that was an assumption you were making.  It's certainly a manifold by the frame bundle argument.  When the derivative is invertible and the manifold has no self-covering then it's a Lie group.   If you allow degenerate maps then I suppose the question is more open-ended.   But I don't see a reason for there to be a group structure when allowing degenerate maps, unless you are in some very special case.

Comment: Presubably the images of the degenerate maps will be something like Riemann submersions to totally geodesic submanifolds.  A fairly special thing.

Comment: @RyanBudney after your interesting comment  I realized that the equation is preserved by composition. In the case that M is a Lie geoup, is the equation preserved by group multiplication? Namely let $f_1,f_2$ satisfy the equation does their (pointwise) product $f_1f_2$ satisfy the eqiation, too. O guess the answer is affirmatove on abelian case.

Comment: In fact your emphasis on "isometric group" and "composition" lead me to realize that the equation is preserved by composition. Thanks for your attention to my question. BTE even if Df is invertible on can not say that f is an isometry for example $z\mapsto z^n$ on circle.

Comment: It's probably not a group for $M = S^2 \times S^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\exp:TM\to M$ in the Lie group context? Do you want something like $X_g\mapsto g\exp(\mathrm{L}_{g^{-1}*}X_g)$, where $\mathrm{L}_g$ denotes left-translation by $g$?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Yes in the Lie group case we use the translation of exp at e to all other elements. In the other word let X_g be a tangent vector at g. There is a unique left invariant ector field on the group whose restriction to g is X_g. Now we start from g by flow of this vectoe field and stop at t=1. The resulting point is exp. I think that is equivalent to what you say

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with the “Riemannian” case. In truth, it doesn’t have much to do with the Riemannian structure at all: $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of all affine maps on $(M,\nabla)$, with the affine connection $\nabla$ given by the Levi-Civita connection.

As you note, this will never have a natural Lie group structure unless $M$ is 0-dimensional, since it will always contain the constant maps. If we make the additional restriction that $f$ be a diffeomorphism, however, we get the group of affine transformations, which has been extensively studied and is well-known to be a Lie group when $M$ has finitely many connected components. For compact Riemannian manifolds, the identity component of the group of affine transformations coincides with the identity component of the isometry group.

Regardless of whether we use diffeomorphisms, it is a standard exercise in differential geometry to prove that affine maps are determined entirely by their value and derivative at a single point, so the dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ will be at most $\dim(M)+\dim(M)^2$.

It isn’t a very cohesive space most of the time, though: it will always contain both a copy of $M$ (the constant maps) and the identity map, and a path between a constant map and the identity would constitute a homotopy, which can only occur for $M$ contractible. Thus, in the generic case, it’ll probably just be $M$ together with an isolated point corresponding to the identity map.

In the Lie groups case, it’s essentially the same.
Note that if $f$ satisfies the condition, then so does $\mathrm{L}_g\circ f$. Thus, $f$ is of the form $\mathrm{L}_g\circ f_0$, where $f_0$ fixes a point, which we will predictably choose to be $e$. I think it follows that the space you end up with will be something like $G\times\mathrm{Hom}(G,G)$. Again, this won’t naturally be a Lie group outside of the discrete case, but if we restrict to diffeomorphisms, I think we get the Lie group $G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your first paragraph:" $\mathcal{H}$ is the group of affine  maps" as you noted in your answer it is not realy the case because of constant maps and also $z\mapsto z^k$ on circle. So O wonder if there are some other kind of pathological maps. Any way the example in the post shows that the identity is not isolated.

Comment: What is this dimension for circle torus  or spher? BTW what is your definition of affine maps when the map is not at least local diffeomorphism?

Comment: For having a Lie structure, the case 0 dimensional is not the only relevant case. Please look at the example

Comment: @AliTaghavi I’m not sure what you’re referring to in my first paragraph. Perhaps you misread? Also, I don’t think there is much chance of pathological examples; as far as smooth maps go, affine maps are exceptionally well-behaved. Finally, the example in your post is rather specific in that you have chosen a contractible Lie group, so in that *specific* case you can find a homotopy from the identity to a constant map. As I said, this will almost never happen. Try, for example, any Lie group that isn’t diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So we get the holomorph of group?(your last word). But I wonder what is the reason and detail  of your  answer? Can you dummarize your answer in a precise manner in one short psragraph? Thanks again for your attention. my underestanding is that the equation implies that f maps the geodesocs to geodesics. But I wonder  what is the details of your answer.

Comment: In the lie group case there is an alternative candidate for group structure on $\mathcal{H}$, pointeise multiplication. Os it really closed under this multiplication? May I ask you to read the previous comment conversations  and the question agaon carefully?

Comment: I’m starting to get the impression that you aren’t actually reading the things I’m writing. Again, I would encourage you to compute a nontrivial example (try $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ or even $\mathbb{R}^2\rtimes\mathrm{SO}(2)$) for yourself before continuing to ask me these questions. As for distilling everything into a short paragraph, mathematics cannot always be spoon-fed to you. If you are struggling with concepts like affine maps, then you may find more luck on our [sister site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), where more elementary mathematical inquiries are probably better suited.

Comment: I read your answer but it does not contain about pointwise multiplication in the group case. Right?

Comment: I did not worked much with affine maps but i now that it is a map which pull back the connection to itself. Regarding the sister site, the participant of MO can judge about a question and they vote either in + or vite to close. The point is that it is better that we refrain from non mathematical comments in MO

Comment: So if you realy find this question as a trivial post please vote to close

Comment: You have misunderstood me. I’m saying that the numerous *computational* questions regarding affine maps, like the ones you are asking in the comments here, are probably more suited to our other site. You should recall the elementary fact that all the connected components of a Lie group are necessarily diffeomorphic, so my answer *does* say that you won’t get any kind of Lie group in most cases. I continue to ask for you to actually compute a nontrivial example because you do not seem willing to listen to me and instead insist that I have not read what you have written carefully enough.

Comment: I should admit that most part of your answer and your comment is not clear for me. In particular there is no a proof in your answer.Could you please give a reference investigate this equation.or can we start a chat?

Comment: For affine maps, you can probably find what you want to know in Chapter VI (“Transformations”) of Kobayashi and Nomizu’s *Foundations of Differential Geometry*, Vol 1. For contractibility, you can probably find that in any elementary topology textbook. For the Lie groups version, note that if $f(e)=e$, then $f(\exp(X))=\exp(f_*X)$, so you should probably be able to say $f(g)f(\exp(X))=f(g)\exp(f_*X)=f(g\exp(X))$.

Comment: Very helpful comment thank you